# default command paramters in a many column insert

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, .net-3.5

I have a series of inserts to be made on a table with a very large number of columns, e.g.:

```
INSERT INTO Table1 (A,B,C,...,Z) VALUES (@a,@b,@c,...,@z)
```

All the fields (A through Z) are nullable.  You cannot perform the insert if you fail to explicitly set a command parameter that's been written in the command text.

Since the column names are not really sequential (all have pretty random names), is there an easy way to loop through the parameters in the command text and set them to `DBNull.Value`?   Or do I manually have to write out:

```
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@a", DBNull.Value);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@b", DBNull.Value);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@c", DBNull.Value);
...
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@z", DBNull.Value);
```

Or is the proper solution to build which columns are actually in-use and concatenate them together (and used parameters), then set the used parameters?

I tend to shy away from concatenation solutions for queries to avoid potential injection attacks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's a more concise/cleaner way to set each parameter to null:

```
foreach (var param in new[] { "@a", "@b", ... })
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue(param, DBNull.Value);
```

I would also tend to shy away from the concatenation solution, but that might be different if your columns have default values defined in the DB, which would(?) be overwritten if you explicitly set them null in your `insert` statement.

Comment: I think say if I were to only need to set @a, and the rest left as null: I would go ahead and set @a.  Then perform the loop similar to your answer, only adding a check to only add the param as null if the param list on the command doesn't already contain that param.

Answer (score 2):

Yes you can probably write code that will read the column names and set them to a default of NULL, the downside of that is it will require higher privileges to read the system database.

I would strongly recommend you consider writting a stored procedure like,

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[spInsertTable1]
    @a type = NULL,
    @b type = NULL,
    @c type = NULL,
    -- ...
    @z type = NULL
AS
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO Table1 (A, B, C, ...., Z) VALUES
    (@a, @b, @c, ..., @z)
END
```

You can them call it like,

```
command.CommandText = "dbo.spInsertTable1";
command.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
command.Paramaters.AddWithValue("@a", somevalue);
// No more are needed the stored procedure will default them to NULL.
```

Answer (score 1):

You would need to execute something against the table to get the table definition first, then you can iterate through that definition and build your params.

So you could do a "select top 0 * from tableName", retrieve that into a datareader, then loop through the fields like so:

```
 for(int i=0;i<reader.FieldCount;i++)
 {
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@" + reader.GetName(i), DBNull.Value);
 }
```

That assumes each field is represented identically as a parameter.

Answer (score 1):

One solution would be to create an array that stores your different parameter names, iterate over it to set each of them to DBNull if you're not setting their value, like so:

```
// Assume paramNames is an array of strings containing each paramter name
foreach(strign param in paramNames)
{
    // Note: 'SettingValue()' and 'value' are a placeholders, as I don't 
    // know how you're determining which parameters are being used.
    if( SettingValue(param) )
    {
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue(param, value);
    }
    else
    {
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue(param, DBNull.Value);
    }
}
```

I agree with shying away from a concatenation solution.  One thing to ask yourself is: If you have so many unused (and nullable) parameters in your insert, why do you have them in the first place?  You should be able to perform the INSERT without including them to begin with.

If you need them for future reference, you can create a stored procedure in your database, rather than using a parameterized query, and give the nullable parameters default values.  You would then only have to specify the parameters in use.